# How to have Haskell Data.Map module available for import with stack tool and environment?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'd like to import `Data.Map`. I'm using stack, after adding map to `package.yaml` to my project as follows:

```
name: space-age
version: 1.2.0.6

dependencies:
  - base

library:
  exposed-modules: SpaceAge
  source-dirs: src
  ghc-options: -Wall
  dependencies:
  - map
  # - foo       # List here the packages you
  # - bar       # want to use in your solution.

tests:
  test:
    main: Tests.hs
    source-dirs: test
    dependencies:
      - space-age
      - hspec
```

But when executing `stack ghci` I still have the following error:

```
In the dependencies for space-age-1.2.0.6:
    map needed, but the stack configuration has no specified version (no package with that name found, perhaps there is a typo in a package's build-depends or an
        omission from the stack.yaml packages list?)
needed since space-age is a build target.
```

Here is the project's `stack.yaml`:

```
resolver: lts-15.8
```

I have the impresson that with proper specification of modules needed, stack should install `Data.Map` for my project.

Could you please give me some pointer on how I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no *map* package on Hackage. If you look in the upper left corner of [the documentation of `Data.Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Map.html), you'll see that it's part of the *containers* package:

[image: Snapshot of upper left corner of Hackage documentation]

Add `containers` as a dependency to your `package.yaml` file:

```
library:
  exposed-modules: SpaceAge
  source-dirs: src
  ghc-options: -Wall
  dependencies:
  - containers
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt effective help!
The meta-question is how a beginner to have the concept of the package and understand the convention of the documentation at package? Now, I understand that a package is a container of modules, and the dependency management is done in terms of package.  The package name of a module is on the top left line of a module's documentation at package. I hope this help for the future.